# Why isn't my jQuery script working?

Tags: jquery, tabs, footer, opacity

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.footer-item').hover(function(){

    $(this).addClass(active);
    $('.footer-item active').removeClass('active');

});

});
```

Basically what I want this script to do is change the class on the active icon so it looks more transparent, and the icon that is being hovered over is made more transparent by adding a class.

Comment: `$(this).addClass("active");`

Comment: And `$('.footer-item .active')`

Comment: Thanks guys, its working perfectly now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple issues with your code.

- You need to remove the active class first, otherwise you are adding active, and removing it immediately (essentially doing "nothing".)
- 'active' in addClass should be a string.
- The correct selector for an element with footer-item and active class is '.footer-item.active'

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.footer-item').hover(function(){

      $('.footer-item.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

     });

  });
  ```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.footer-item').hover(function(){

    $('.footer-item.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

});

});
```

```css
.active { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer-item">Item 1</div>
<div class="footer-item">Item 2</div>
<div class="footer-item">Item 3</div>
<div class="footer-item">Item 4</div>
```